# Is there a way to ignore null values when ordering by ascending with Azure Cognitive Search Service?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

In the documentation for the Azure Cognitive Search Service query parameters, in the row for *$orderby* it's mentioned that null values will appear first when ascending order is selected and last when descending.

Is there any way that I can ignore these null values and just start when the value is not null or do I just need to process them after the request to filter the ones with null values?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-filter) clause in the search query: `$filter=A ne null`